# Custom dropdown styling issue: `appearance: none` not working on MacOS on any browser

Tags: html, css, macos, sass, frontend

CSS/SCSS Custom Dropdown Styling Issue: `appearance: none` property not working on MacOS on any browser. What am I missing?

I was trying to make a custom dropdown that shows the color of each item in a circle next to the actual option. However, no matter what I do the default MacOS dropdown is what appears instead (pictured below). I've used the `appearance: none` property as well as the webkit and Mozilla variants yet none of them have worked and I can't figure out how to override it.

I've tried reordering it in a dozen different ways and every possible combination of the three appearance properties with no luck.

[image: dropdown menu with three options, one for black, blue and cobalt respectively.]

Here is the temporary testing styling I am using if it helps, let me know if I'm just missing something obvious.

```
select {
      appearance: none;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      
      background-color: transparent;
      border: none;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #000;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Comment: To create a cross browser custom select, I wouldn't use the select. I would use javascript/html/css to convert it to HTML with divs for example. This will ensure a consistent cross browser experience

Comment: Can you put a runnable snippet into tour question. We need to see how you are creating that circle. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example